# Encryption of Data using SQLCipher

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, sqlcipher

Please refer to [this link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_12_JSONStore_-_Encrypting_sensitive_data_with_FIPS.pdf) for the implementation of the encryption operation of the data in an IBM MobileFirst Project using SQLCipher.

The document states that SQL Cipher is included in MobileFirst for Android, but it does not gives any sample application which depicts this action.
Can anyone share an example for it?

Comment: There are many examples online, try using so's search or google..
For example: 
https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

SQL Cipher is used in JSONStore for encrypting your, JSONStore.
So you need to follow the encryption API.

To encrypt your JSONStore simply `init` it like mentioned here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_gs_javascript.html

```
var collections = {
    ...
    ...
};

// Optional options object.
var options = {

  // Optional username, default 'jsonstore'.
  username : 'carlos',

  // Optional password, default no password.
  password : '123',

  // Optional local key generation flag, default false.
  localKeyGen : false
};

WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options) {
   ...
   ...
}
```

By using `username` and `password` properties in the options object, this then triggers the encryption option in JSONStore. If you do not specify `localKeyGen` this means that the `.init` API will use the Worklight Server to generate the encryption key. If set to `true` this means it will use the weaker local ability to generate it on the device.